# R: plotting a line and horizontal barplot on the same plot

Tags: r

I am trying to combine a line plot and horizontal barplot on the same plot. The difficult part is that the barplot is actually counts of the y values of the line plot.

Can someone show me how this can be done using the example below ?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
x <- c(1:100)
dff <- data.frame(x = x,y1 = sample(-500:500,size=length(x),replace=T), y2 = sample(3:20,size=length(x),replace=T))

counts <- ddply(dff, ~ y1, summarize, y2 = sum(y2))

# line plot
ggplot(data=dff) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y1)) 
# bar plot
ggplot() + geom_bar(data=counts,aes(x=y1,y=y2),stat="identity")
```

I believe what I need is presented in the pseudocode below but I do not know how to write it out in R.

**Apologies. I actually meant the secondary x axis representing the value of counts for the barplot, while primary y-axis is the y1**.

```
ggplot(data=dff) + geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y1)) + geom_bar(data=counts , aes(primary y axis = y1,secondary x axis =y2),stat="identity")
```

[image]

I just want the barplots to be plotted horizontally, so I tried the code below which flip both the line chart and barplot, which is also not I wanted.

```
ggplot(data=dff) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y1)) + 
  geom_bar(data=counts,aes(x=y2,y=y1),stat="identity") + coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can combine two plots in `ggplot` like you want by specifying different `data =` arguments in each `geom_` layer (and none in the original `ggplot()` call).

```
 ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data=dff, aes(x=x,y=y1)) + 
    geom_bar(data=counts,aes(x=y1,y=y2),stat="identity")
```

The following plot is the result. However, since `x` and `y1` have different ranges, are you sure this is what you want?

[image]

Perhaps you want `y1` on the vertical axis for both plots. Something like this works:

ggplot() +
geom_line(data=dff, aes(x=y1 ,y = x)) +
geom_bar(data=counts,aes(x=y1,y=y2),stat="identity", color = "red")  +
coord_flip()

[image]

Comment: These 2 plots are not what I wanted. I  want the line chart to be `aes(x=x,y=y1)` and `aes(primary y axis = y1, secondary y axis =y2)`. Only the barplot would be be horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this. Ans based on your last code you look for a double axis. So using `dplyr` you can store the counts in the same dataframe and then plot all variables. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#Data
x <- c(1:100)
dff <- data.frame(x = x,y1 = sample(-500:500,size=length(x),replace=T), y2 = sample(3:20,size=length(x),replace=T))
#Code
dff %>% group_by(y1) %>% mutate(Counts=sum(y2)) -> dff2
#Scale factor
sf <- max(dff2$y1)/max(dff2$Counts)
# Plot
ggplot(data=dff2)+
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y1),color='blue',size=1)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',aes(x=x,y=Counts*sf),fill='tomato',color='black')+
  scale_y_continuous(name="y1", sec.axis = sec_axis(~./sf, name="Counts"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: any way we can keep the line chart the way it is on your plot except that the `geom_bar` is plotted horizontally, with secondary x -axis representing the counts ?

Comment: @user1769197 Hi, have you tried `coord_flip()`, is the only way I think you can have the plot rotated as you want!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried `coord_flip()` but it flipped both the line chart and barplot. I only it to flip the barplot.